# Error while writing equation

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)} : \\
\begin{align*}
\overline \rho &= $K$ ~\Big( $sinh ~t$ ~- ~$t$\Big)\\
\overline P &= \frac {1}{3} $K$ ~ \Big($sinh~t$ - 8 $sinh$ \frac {1}{2} t  + $3t$\Big)\\
\end {align*}
\end {document}
```

can you tell me why I have error in the right side of the equations?

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `align`, as the material is already in math mode. Use `\sinh` for the hyperbolic sine and `\Bigl` in front of the opening parentheses, `\Bigr` with the closing ones (but in those formulas you don't need larger parentheses). Don't use `~` in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @egreg's comments, I would suggest to replace `\overline` here (too large) with `widebar`, borrowed from the `mathx` font (`mathabx` package) and for the fraction coefficients, medium-sized fractiions, defined in the `nccmath` package. Also, don't load `amsmath`, since `mathtools`does it for you. You can replace *some*  of the `~` with a `thin space` (`\,`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <->  mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)} :
\begin{align*}
\widebar{\rho} &= K \,\bigl( \sinh t  - t \bigr)\\
\widebar{P} &= \mfrac {1}{3}K\, \Bigl(\sinh t  - 8 \sinh  \mfrac {1}{2} t  +  3t \Bigr)
\end {align*}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\bigl` and `\bigr`, if you *really* want larger delimiters. Since you're defining the font shape, use `<->` instead of fixed sizes, as `mathx10` is available in Type1 format.

Comment: You're right. I'll change it at once.